# Python: How to group-by with a list in column

Tags: python, pandas

I am dealing with the following dataframe:

```
   list          orders
[item1, item2]     A
[item10, item1]    A
[item10, item15]   B
```

When I group-by orders the list column disappears completely. Is there a method to group by using lists. My expected outcome would be:

```
      list:                        orders:
[item1, item2, item10, item1]        A
[item10, item15]                     B
```

Comment: Please add code.

Comment: df.groupby('order').sum()

Answer (score 4):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with custom lambda function for flatten nested lists:

```
from  itertools import chain
f = lambda x: list(chain.from_iterable(x))
```

Or:

```
f = lambda x: [z for y in x for z in y]
```

Or:

```
f = lambda x: np.concatenate(x.values)
```

---

```
df = df.groupby('orders')['list'].apply(f).reset_index()
print (df)
  orders                           list
0      A  [item1, item2, item10, item1]
1      B               [item10, item15]
```

If performance is not important (slow in large data):

```
df = df.groupby('orders')['list'].sum().reset_index()
```